# Does the caster level of a spell-like ability satisfy prerequisites of item creation feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, feat-qualifications

Does the caster level of a spell like ability satisfy prerequisite of item creation feats?

### Monster Example: [Devil, Imp](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/imp/)

> **Spell-Like Abilities (CL 6th)**
>
> - Constant — *detect good*, *detect magic*
> - At will — *invisibility* (self only)
> - 1/day — *augury*, *suggestion* (DC 15)
> - 1/week — *commune* (6 questions, CL 12th)

Can the Imp take, for example, [Craft Wondrous Item](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-wondrous-item-item-creation-final/) using the caster levels of its spell-like abilities to meet the prerequisite of the feat?

Comment: Related: [Does a Qinggon monk fulfill the requirements to take craft magical arms and armor feat?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83224)

Answer (score 9):

### It does not

This has been (briefly) clarified on this [FAQ item](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qp0):

> *Item Creation Feats: Does having a caster level from a spell-like ability meet the caster level prerequisite for selecting an item creation feat?*
>
> No.

They can be used to satisfy the magic item's requirement ([FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qp1)), but not the crafting feat requirements.

Answer (score 3):

**No, but the imp can still craft**

If the imp takes the [Master Craftsman](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-craftsman-final/) feat and ranks in the relevant Craft or Profession skill then it can craft using its skill rank as its caster level.  It still needs the relevant item creation feat as well.

The description of the Master Craftsman feat also clarifies that spell-like abilities do not count (emphasis mine):

> **Normal:**  Only *spellcasters* can qualify for the Craft Magic Arms and Armour and Craft Wondrous Items feats.